# Calculate Force Needed to Squeeze a set of prongs together?

Tags: metals

I have an anodizing rack that has hundreds of prongs. These prongs are made of titanium and need to be squeezed together in order to place the parts on the rack. I am wondering how I would calculate the force needed to make the prongs touch so that parts can be added?

I have seen some people saying to use F=kx treating the prongs as a spring, would this be the best way? Any help is appreciated.

[image: titanium prongs]

Answer (score 1):

Using [Hooke's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hooke%27s_law) $${\bf F}=-k{\bf x}$$  will *not* work.

Note that the equation above relates the *extension* of a spring or spring-like material, $\bf x$ to the restoring force, $\bf F$ (and are both opposite in direction, along the same line). It says nothing about a (perpendicular) force that causes the deflection of the tip of a substance (even if that substance can be deflected and move back to its initial position, similar to a "spring").

That is, Hooke's explicitly states the applied force is always *colinear* with the displacement $\bf x$ and therefore *not* at right angles to it, which appears to be what you are suggesting.